# PHP regex to get WordPress category slug from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am trying to get the category slug from the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` using a pre_match pattern, but it's not working.

For example, the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns `/category/current-affairs/` and I want to set `current-affairs` to a variable that I want to use.

So far I came up with this but it's not working
`^\/category\/(?:\/(\w+))*$/g`

Any help with this will be very much appreciated.

Comment: regex101.com is the best tool to develop and analyse regex.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need regex. wp has a function do it for you:

```
if(is_category()) {
    $category = get_query_var('cat');
    $current_cat = get_category($cat);
    echo 'The slug is ' . $current_cat->slug;
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex [`^\/category\/(?:\/(\w+))*$/g`](https://regex101.com/r/mNaYW7/1/) matches:

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match a forward slash `\/`
- Match `category`
- Match a forward slash `\/`
- A non capturing group `(?:` repeated zero or more times `*`
- In this non capturing group, match a forward slash and in a capturing group `\w` one or more times`\/(\w+)`
- The end of the string `$`

With this part `\/(\w+)` you are trying to match `current-affairs`

But this part matches

- A forward slash `\/`
- Capture in a group `[A-Za-z0-9_]` one or more times
  But your text has a hyphen `-` in it.

The full pattern expect to match for example `/category`, 2 forward slashes `//` and `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`

It would match:

`/category//currentaffairs`

But not

`/category//currentaffairs/`
`/category/currentaffairs/`
`/category//current-affairs/`
`/category//current-affairs`

I think you can get your match like this:

[`^\/category\/([\w-]+)\/$`](https://regex101.com/r/4bJMay/2)

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way is to explode the uri to an array and read the 3rd value:

```
$request_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$category = $request_uri[2];
```

Answer (score -1):

Your pattern isn't working for a few reasons:

1. You're trying to match `//` (in this section `\/(?:\/`)
2. `\w` doesn't match `-`. It matches `a-zA-Z0-9_`
3. You're always ensuring something follows the last `/`: `(?:\/(\w+))*$`

#### Code

**Note**: The regex below uses a different regular expression delimiter (in the link, for example, I use `@` instead of `/` to delimit the pattern). This allows us to use `/` inside the pattern without first having to escape it.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Fbe7LY/1)

```
/category/\K[^/]*
```

- `/category/` Match this literally.
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.
- `[^/]*` Match any character except `/` any number of times.

#### Usage

```
$re = '@/category/\K[^/]*@';
preg_match_all($re, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
\/category(.*)
```